# Proving logarithmic property for series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, $a_n>0$. I need to prove that if $\alpha>0$ and $n_0 \in N$ exist, such that for every $n \ge n_0$, it is true that $\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{a_n})}{\ln(n)} \ge 1 + \alpha$ then the series converges. Also if $n_0 \in N$, such that for every $n \ge n_0$ it is true that $\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{a_n})}{\ln(n)} \le 1$, the series is divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Take the exponential of both sides:

\begin{align}
\frac{\log(\frac{1}{a_n})}{\log(n)} \ge 1 + \alpha&\iff-\log a_n\ge( 1 + \alpha)\log n\iff\log a_n\le-( 1 + \alpha)\log n)\\
&\iff a_n\le\frac1{n^{1+\alpha}},
\end{align}
which  is a  convergent *Riemann series*.

Similarly, the second  hypothesis  is equivalent to $\;a_n\ge \dfrac 1n$.